# Lexical or Preprocessor issue GroupcentricSDK_ARC.h file not found

Tags: iphone, xcode4.6.3

I get this error . . .

```
Lexical or Preprocessor issue GroupcentricSDK_ARC.h file not found
```

when I try to build an application that has already been built on another pc. The application is using Groupcentric Framework. I added the framework into project but again its showing GroupcentricSDK_ARC.h file not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. i downloaded the new Framework SDK from GitHub and did some changes. its started working

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the project include path contains the file.

Go to Project->Build Settings -> Header Search Path and then add the path to the header file there.

Comment: i found GroupGroupcentricSDK_ARC.h file inside the framework folder. i added the entire Headers folder contains GroupGroupcentricSDK_ARC.h file into the project. Now i am getting different errors.now i am  getting   ""Apple mach-o linker error”      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_gc_TTTTimeIntervalFormatter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SocialVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Do not add the file to the project! Just update the Header search path in the project